# Questions about multiplicative homomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebraic-groups, gr.group-theory

Regard $K=\mathbb{R}-\lbrace{0\rbrace}$ as a multiplication group. Let $f:K\to K$ be a multiplication homormorphism.

Question 1. Whether that $f$ is surjective implies that $f$ is injective?

Question 2. Whether that $f$ is injective implies that $f$ is surjective?

Question 3. $g: x\to x^b$ is a multiplication homormorphism of $K$ where $b=n/m, (n,m)=1$,$n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m$ is an odd integer. How to find any other multiplication homormorphism of $K$ than this form. Any example?

Edit. Emil Jeřábek gave other explicit examples:
$h: x\to |x|^r$ or $x\to sgn(x)|x|^r.$  Of course, $hg$ is also ok.

Any other explicit ones?

Perhaps, these questions look like homework, but not easy to me to answer  (my major is not in algebraic theory).

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplication homomorphism", perhaps just a homomorphism? And why the tag "algebraic groups"?

Comment: To add to Toink’s answer, there are also simple explicit examples for Q3: consider $f(x)=|x|^r$ or $f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(x)|x|^r$ for any $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yeah. I should not have  omitted these possibility.

Comment: any other form of example except Tonik's?


Comment: The endomorphisms I mentioned are continuous. The other half of the story is that is every other endomorphism is neither Baire measurable nor Lebesgue measurable, and you need the axiom of choice to prove their existence, hence there is pretty much no way to describe them explicitly. Toink’s construction (with the proviso that elements of the basis can be mapped to arbitrary elements of $K$, and you have additionally a choice to map $−1$ to either $1$ or $−1$) describes *all* endomorphisms.

Comment: Regarding your last edit, $hg$ is of the same form as $h$. These endomorphisms form a group.

Comment: Yes, nice answer.

Comment: @woodbass: The question seems  well-intended but not carefully enough constructed (including the use of "multiplication" in the header when "multiplicative" is apparently intended).    Selecting the right tags is also important.   Anyway, you should be able to click on a check mark to accept an answer.   

Comment: @woodbass: look for the check mark beside the answer, and click it. That's how you accept an answer. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times (\mathbb{R}^+,\cdot )\to K$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (-1)^xy$ (considering $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to contain 0 and 1).
There is also an isomorphism $(\mathbb R,+)\to(\mathbb R^+,\cdot)$ given by $x\mapsto exp(x)$.

So for all your questions it is enough to consider $K':= (\mathbb R,+)$, since $K \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times K'$
But $K'$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. So you can pick any basis (which will be uncountable) and then do something on it giving you a lot of endomorphisms of $K'$.

Both questions 1 and 2 are false, since on the uncountable basis of $K'$ there are injective but not surjective set-maps (and vice versa), that extend to an endomorphism of $K'$.